# MessageBox appears but does not pop up

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, messagebox

I have a message box that has ok or cancel as options to ensure the user wishes to change the name of a company. However, this message box doesn't pop up on the current screen, instead it just appears on the windows task bar and blinks there.
May I know how do I make it appear?

```
    var ConfirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to change the name of the Company?", "Confirm Update!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

edit: This is in asp.net web forms.

Comment: This is an ASP.Net Webforms application?

Comment: @Archer at least he tagged so.

Comment: @SeM That's why I'm asking, because trying to show a dialog makes no sense in that scenario.

Comment: @Archer yeap, I know, I didn't meant that you was not paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand and distinct the programs that runs on desktop, and the programs that runs on server and send the results to some web browser.

In this case the MessageBox, is creates new window on the desktop side – is not work for a web application, not make sense at all.

To make a message box in a browser, you need to think different – you make the message box using some css and javascript and you render that on the page on the browser.You handle the events with javascript and/or post back

get some ideas: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_alert.asp

[image]